# I can't create new project with android API 17

Tags: android

I have delete `android-17` in my `../sdk/flatform` folder, and reinstall it, but nothing changed, my Android Studio can't create new project with API lv 17. Only API 17 is error. I CAN create new project with API 19 and other API not only 17.
I use Android Studio 0.5.4

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kicFn.jpg

Comment: Why do you want that? I would never use an older SDK version that the newest. Btt did you restart AS?

Comment: Did you remove API 17 properly via the Android SDK Manager or via a file explorer? If via a file explorer, then you may have broken some links internally.

Comment: @ Rekire Vâng, tôi có thể sử dụng vesion mới nhất. Nhưng tôi không biết tại sao lỗi hãng Android của tôi.
@ChuongPham: I delete it by Android SDK manager.

Comment: For the API levels that you have downloaded, did you also download the source codes of those APIs.